# Oracle SQL Developer: export a database in a special order depending on the foreign keys contraints

Tags: database, foreign-keys, export, oracle-sqldeveloper

Using Oracle SQL Developer, you can export databases to SQL scripts (INSERT statements only) using the "Tools" > "Database Export" menu entry. The problem is that the table are exported in the alphabetical order, and it doesn't seem to be possible to change that order (or I didn't find how to proceed at least).

It is a problem because, when you have foreign key constraints, it's possible that the exported SQL script can't be imported back, since parents must have been inserted before children. Lets say B is the parent and A the child, the (simplified) Oracle SQL Developer exported SQL script file will be:

```
INSERT A; <-- error: B is needed
INSERT B;
```

So, has anyone a solution to:

- either export a database with automatically ordered tables insert statements depending on the foreign key constraints,
- or export a database while manually specifying the order of the tables insert statements,
- or disable temporarily the foreign key constraints to be able to import a script alphabetically ordered, and re-enable the constraints afterwards

?

PS: the idea is to let the tables structures as is, and only to import data.

Comment: Are you trying to clone Database?

Comment: @Lokesh No, just to have a SQL script inserting the data I currently have, that I can use later to reinit a database.

Comment: I saw an option to automatically include dependencies in Sql developer. May be you can try that.

Comment: @Lokesh Do you remember where did you see this option?

Comment: check this link: http://perumal.org/sql-developer-database-export-wizard-to-export-ddl-and-data-as-dml/

Comment: @Lokesh It seems to work, but the idea were to let the tables structures as is, and only to import data. I edited the question to be more clear. Thanks anyway `;)`

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to manually specify the order of the tables insert statements.

In SQL Developer: **Tools > Export database.**

If you only want the data in your tables, uncheck the **"Export DDL code"** option.

In the **"Specify data"** window, you can now manually specify the tables you need **in  the insertion order** (in your example, table B before table A).

That should do the trick! It just did for me at least.

An automatic way to do this would be nicer though, as it can be a bit tedious if you have lots of tables...

Comment: is there any automatic way?